# SQL compare rows between groups and show the missing

Tags: sql

I have the following data from a SQL DB. There are 98 columns in total this is an extract of 4 to illustrate what I would like to to and in the final query I would expect to require 51 of them. There are 15 million rows to this table.

```html
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
|    RatePlan     | RatePlanCharge  | SubscriptionVersion | RatePlanChargePreDiscountMRR |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 7                   | 90                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Online Support  | Online Support  | 7                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Module Support  | Module Support  | 7                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 6                   | 90                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Module Support  | Module Support  | 6                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 5                   | 90                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Premium Support | Premium Support | 5                   | 40                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Module Support  | Module Support  | 5                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 4                   | 90                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Module Support  | Module Support  | 4                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 3                   | 90                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Online Support  | Online Support  | 3                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Module Support  | Module Support  | 3                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 2                   | 90                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Online Support  | Online Support  | 2                   | 0                            |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Main Product    | Main Product    | 1                   | 85                           |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |
| Online Support  | Online Support  | 1                   | 0                            |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
```

This table shows each change to a subscription. We can see;

- At version 3 Module Support is added
- At version 4 Online Support is removed
- At version 5 Premium Support is added
- At version 6 Premium Support is removed
- At version 7 Online Support is added

What I want to do is run a query that will return rows missing from the current version that were present in the previous version, as below.

```html
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    RATEPLAN     | RATEPLANCHARGE  | SUBSCRIPTIONVERSION | RATEPLANCHARGEPREDISCOUNTMRR |  SUBSCRIPTIONVERSION_MISSINGFROM |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                 |                 |                     |                              |                                |
| Premium Support | Premium Support | 5                   | 40                           | 6                              |
|                 |                 |                     |                              |                                |
| Online Support  | Online Support  | 3                   | 0                            | 4                              |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, what sql is this? (oracle,mysql etc)

Comment: MS SQL, should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT n.RatePlan, n.SubscriptionVersion,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.RatePlan IS NOT NULL AND p.RatePlan IS NOT NULL THEN 'Continued' 
        WHEN c.RatePlan IS     NULL AND p.RatePlan IS NOT NULL THEN 'Discontinued'
        WHEN c.RatePlan IS NOT NULL AND p.RatePlan IS     NULL THEN 'New'
        ELSE '!' END AS Status,
FROM (
    -- The labels we need are everything in the current and previous version.
    SELECT DISTINCT RatePlan, SubscriptionVersion
    FROM (
        -- Plans in the current verson.
        SELECT RatePlan, SubscriptionVersion FROM WhateverItIs
        UNION
        -- Plans in the previous version.
        SELECT p.RatePlan, w.SubscriptionVersion
        FROM WhateverItIs w
            INNER JOIN WhateverItIs p ON p.SubscriptionVersion + 1 = w.SubscriptionVersion
    ) T
) AS n
    LEFT JOIN WhateverItIs c ON n.RatePlan = c.RatePlan AND n.SubscriptionVersion = c.SubscriptionVersion -- Is it current?
    LEFT JOIN WhateverItIs p ON n.RatePlan = p.RatePlan AND n.SubscriptionVersion = p.SubscriptionVersion + 1 -- Is it previous?
```

I don't generally think of `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but indeed that works too.

```
SELECT ISNULL(c.RatePlan, p.RatePlan) AS RatePlan,
    ISNULL(c.SubscriptionVersion, p.SubscriptionVersion + 1) AS SubscriptionVersion,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.RatePlan IS NOT NULL AND p.RatePlan IS NOT NULL THEN 'Continued' 
        WHEN c.RatePlan IS     NULL AND p.RatePlan IS NOT NULL THEN 'Discontinued'
        WHEN c.RatePlan IS NOT NULL AND p.RatePlan IS     NULL THEN 'New'
        ELSE '!' 
    END AS Status,
FROM WhateverItIs c
    FULL OUTER JOIN WhateverItIs p ON c.RatePlan = p.RatePlan AND c.SubscriptionVersion = p.SubscriptionVersion + 1
```

Comment: I get the following error

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near 'n'.

When replacing WhateverItIs with my table name SubscriptionsHistory.

When attempting your first solution.

Comment: Comma after `AS Status`.

Comment: This is superb.

I've made some changes, as written it was attempting to match on the rate plan and the version but I need to also take the SubscriptionReference into account. I've obviously been over zealous though as my version below does not bring in the Discontinued rows. The WHERE and ORDERBY are just there to validate data and will be removed from the final query.

Comment: `SELECT 
  n.RatePlanCharge, 
  n.SubscriptionVersion, 
  n.SubscriptionReference, 
  CASE WHEN c.RatePlanCharge IS NOT NULL 
  AND p.RatePlanCharge IS NOT NULL THEN 'Continued' WHEN c.RatePlanCharge IS NULL 
  AND p.RatePlanCharge IS NOT NULL THEN 'Discontinued' WHEN c.RatePlanCharge IS NOT NULL 
  AND p.RatePlanCharge IS NULL THEN 'New' ELSE '!' END AS Status 
FROM 
  (
    -- The labels we need are everything in the current and previous version.
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT RatePlanCharge, 
      SubscriptionVersion, 
      SubscriptionReference 
    FROM `

Comment: `(
        -- Plans in the current verson.
        SELECT 
          RatePlanCharge, 
          SubscriptionVersion, 
          SubscriptionReference 
        FROM 
          SubscriptionsHistory 
        Where 
          SubscriptionReference = 'A-REFERENCE' 
        UNION 
          -- Plans in the previous version.
        SELECT 
          p.RatePlanCharge, 
          w.SubscriptionVersion, 
          w.SubscriptionReference 
        FROM`

Comment: `SubscriptionsHistory w 
          INNER JOIN SubscriptionsHistory p ON p.SubscriptionVersion + 1 = w.SubscriptionVersion 
          AND p.SubscriptionReference = w.SubscriptionReference 
          AND p.RatePlanCharge = w.RatePlanCharge 
        Where 
          w.SubscriptionReference = 'A-REFERENCE'
      ) T
  ) AS n 
  LEFT JOIN SubscriptionsHistory c ON n.RatePlanCharge = c.RatePlanCharge 
  AND n.SubscriptionVersion = c.SubscriptionVersion 
  AND n.SubscriptionReference = c.SubscriptionReference -- Is it current?`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN SubscriptionsHistory p ON n.RatePlanCharge = p.RatePlanCharge 
  AND n.SubscriptionVersion = p.SubscriptionVersion + 1 
  AND n.SubscriptionReference = p.SubscriptionReference -- Is it previous?
ORDER BY 
  n.SubscriptionVersion DESC`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a self outer join. This finds the dropped rows. A similar one can be used to find the added rows.

```
SELECT * from tablename prev
LEFT JOIN tablename curr
WHERE curr.SUBSCRIPTIONVERSION = prev.SUBSCRIPTIONVERSION + 1
AND curr.SUBSCRIPTIONVERSION IS NULL
```